# create a variable based on lagged values in the same variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this structure where I have `groups` and also have the first value for the variable in a group. `var4`. Other values in `var4` are calculated based on the lagged value within the same group.

I tried using lag but it does not work with referencing the same variable `var4`

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: 1. don't post images of your data (instead, post your data using `dput()`); 2. Clarify what you are trying to achieve (i.e. show your desired output). 3). Show what you have tried thus far. Your problem is probably straightfoward and you are likely to receive rapid help from this community, but you need to be more explicit about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want to do:

```r
df |>
  group_by(groups) |>
  arrange(year) |>
  mutate(temp = if_else(year == 1, var1, var2 * var3),
         var4 = cumsum(temp))
```